# Problem with the page output function of a double-linked list

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

Page output of list items. There are count/2 items on the page. Since the end may not be equal to this number, but be less, it must be handled separately. I enter boundaries upper and lower, when the lower boundary is reached the tail is output separately and this is the whole problem...

```
void ShowList(hwnd* hwnd){
    int id = 0, count = 10, CountElementstInEnd;
    node* temp;
    node* head = hwnd->head;
    node* UpLimit = hwnd->head;
    node* LwLimit = hwnd->tail;

    if(!head) return;
    for(int i = 0; i < count/2 ; i++)
        UpLimit = UpLimit->next;
    CountElementstInEnd = hwnd->size % (count/2) - 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < CountElementstInEnd; i++)
        LwLimit = LwLimit->prev;
    temp = LwLimit;
    char c;

    do
    {
        system("cls");
        puts      (" ID      NAME          SEX        SPORT          BORN    GROWTH ");
        for(int i = 0; i < count/2 ; i++, id++){
            ///Output the records at the end (their number may not be a multiple of count/2)
            if(head == LwLimit){
                for(int i = 0; i < CountElementstInEnd; i++, id++){
                    printf(" %-2.2d   %-12.12s    %-6.6s   %-16.16s  %-4.4d      %-3.3d  \n", id, temp->data->name, temp->data->sex, temp->data->sport, temp->data->born, temp->data->growth);
                    temp = temp->next;
                }
                temp = LwLimit;
                id-=CountElementstInEnd;
                break;
            }
            ///normal output
            printf(" %-2.2d   %-12.12s    %-6.6s   %-16.16s  %-4.4d      %-3.3d  \n", id, head->data->name, head->data->sex, head->data->sport, head->data->born, head->data->growth);
            head = head->next;
        }
        ///users input 1 - next, 2 - prev
         while(1){
            c = getch();
            if (c == 0x31 && (head == LwLimit)){
                for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    head = head->prev;
                id -= count;
                break;
            }
            if (c == 0x31 && (head != UpLimit)){
                for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    head = head->prev;
                id -= count;
                break;
            }
            else if(c == 0x32 || c == 27)
                break;
        }
        
    }
    while(c != 27);
}
```

The function works, but if we share to the end and then go back, it skips 1 page. If we go back when it reaches not by count but by count/2 entries, the output will loop to the last page and "tail".

```
if (c == 0x31 && (head == hwnd->tail)){
        head = head->prev->prev;
        break;
    }
```

then the output will loop at the end... Is there any way out of this situation? =(

https://pastebin.com/J2bnc151

Comment: Yes, I have already corrected it. At the end of the link to the file, it has a button 4 list output by page

Comment: Rethink! What will you do if the "page size" increases to 3... to 4... to 7??? Write more code that struggles? Perhaps the "rewind" operation needs to use a loop just like the "display and forward" operation... (And, `modulo` calculations would maintain uniformity in the output.)

Comment: My plan was to first do the output for the two elements for simplicity, and then automate the right part of the code with loops. This approach seemed simpler to me, or are you leaning towards the fact that the function is written completely wrong?

Comment: Your "forward" loop deals with a single "record" and the possibility of a next. The "rewind", as written, is hard-coded to expect and deal with two records at a time. Can you make the "rewind" back up one step and keep reversing (looping) until `idx % 2 == 0`? Every batch displayed begins with a value of `idx` whose mod2 is `0`. Then, trivial to change `2` to `n` to shown `n` records per page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible (working) example of how you might achieve your goals:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_s { // abbreviated struct declaration
    char *name;
    struct node_s *prev, *next;
} node;

const int pagesz = 2; // a "working" page size to adapt

void ShowList( node *head ) {
    int id = 0;
    char c = 0;

    while( c != 27 ) { // UGLY "magic number"
        node *p = head; // a working copy

        // output the "page" (without "cls")
        puts( " ID      NAME" );
        for( int i = 0; i < pagesz && p; i++, p = p->next )
            printf(" %2d   %s\n", id + i, p->name );

        while( 1 ) {
            c = getchar();
            if( c == 27) // again, meaningless magic number
                break;

            if( c == '+' ) { // '+' == "advance"
                for( int i = 0; i < pagesz; i++ )
                    if( head->next )
                        head = head->next, id++;
                break;
            }

            if( c == '-' ) { // '-' == "rewind"
                for( int i = 0; i < pagesz; i++ )
                    if( head->prev )
                        head = head->prev, id--;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    node arr[] = {
        { "Grumpy 0"},
        { "Dopey 1" },
        { "Doc 2" },
        { "Sneezy 3" },
        { "Bashful 4" },
        { "Sleepy 5" },
        { "Happy 6" },
    };

    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < sizeof arr/sizeof arr[0]; i++ )
        arr[i].prev = &arr[i-1], arr[i].next = &arr[i+1];

    arr[0].prev = arr[i-1].next = NULL;

    ShowList( arr );

    return 0;
}
```

```
 ID      NAME
  0   Grumpy 0
  1   Dopey 1
+
 ID      NAME
  2   Doc 2
  3   Sneezy 3
+
 ID      NAME
  4   Bashful 4
  5   Sleepy 5
-
 ID      NAME
  2   Doc 2
  3   Sneezy 3
+
 ID      NAME
  4   Bashful 4
  5   Sleepy 5
+
 ID      NAME
  6   Happy 6
-
 ID      NAME
  4   Bashful 4
  5   Sleepy 5
```

Comment: How easy it is, I'm so bad( thank you

Comment: This code is not the 'modulo' that I suggested in the comments. But, it is simple (and that's a good thing.) Glad to be of assistance. `:-)`